# doctrine join column joined on other entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have 3 tables:

Post -> Type  -> Category

I need to get the category on the Post entity passing per Type to use this on a filter form

This is possible?

like a join and subjoin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to filter `Post`'s by `Category`.

Like with any other field you wish to filter by, you have to add a `Form` to the filter's `FormBuilder`. The problem in this case is that the `Entity` bound to the form doesn't have the property `category`. It's its property `type` who does.

Thus, you need to tell the `Form` how to access the right property. This is achieved by using the `property_path` option. [Here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#property-path)'s the documentation for it.

You would do something like this in your filter's `Type`:

```
    $builder
        ->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'label'         => 'Category',
            'data_class'    => 'Category',
            'property_path' => 'type.category',
        ))
    ;
```

The `property_path` option is very powerful. It will accept any path that the `PropertyAccess` component does. Read its documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html).

Comment: Via Doctrine i can do this? mapping a entity field?

Comment: Do you mean as a way of avoiding joins? No, you can't.

Comment: No. I need to join but i only can a field on the entity. make some like this "select p.id,p.name,c.id,c.name from post p inner join type t on t.id=p.type inner join category c on c.id category" with only the mapping

Answer (score 0):

Multiple joins are possible in doctrine. Please, read [this section in doctrine documentation.](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins)

Comment: You dont understand. I need on my entity Post, the entity Category on a field. I need to use this on a form.